# exporting data and schema of database

Tags: database, backup, db2, export

1. Does database backup exports only data or schema as well?
2. I have one PC running DB2 database server1 and having a database XYZ,Now I want to create replica of this database on another pc running db2 database.
3. I don't want to do this without using affecting db server1, I don't want it to stop or hang
4. can I use **db2 BACKUP DATABASE tc TO "D:\XYZ" WITH 2 BUFFERS BUFFER 1024 PARALLELISM 1 WITHOUT PROMPTING**

Answer (score 2):

BACKUP DATABASE writes an exact image of the database (configuration, physical layout of data files, schema and data).

You can use the copy the resulting backup image to another server and use RESTORE DATABASE to restore a copy of it.  If the same drives / directories do not exist on the new server, you may need to [perform a redirected restore](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006249.html) to change the location of the database's data files on the new server.

The BACKUP DATABASE command that you provide will take an offline (cold) backup of the database, which requires that no users are connected to the database.  If the database is enabled for [archive logging](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0051344.html), you can take an online backup:

```
backup database tc online to "D:\XYZ" include logs
```

I removed the unnecessary options from your BACKUP DATABASE command (DB2 will automatically select appropriate values).  Adding "include logs" will make your life easier when doing a restore and subsequent rollforward.

Answer (score 1):

schema backup

db2look -d  -e -z  -o ddl_schema1.sql

db2 -x "select 'export to ' || rtrim(tabname) || '.ixf of ixf MODIFIED BY lobsinfile MESSAGES ' || rtrim(tabname) \
 || '.msg select * from ' || rtrim(tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname) ||';'from syscat.tables where type = 'T' \ 
and tabschema in (', ...)" > schema_tables.sql

or

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fi/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0057038.html

or

CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_COPY_SCHEMA('SOURCE_SCHEMA', 'TARGET_SCHEMA',
      'COPY', NULL, 'SOURCETS1 , SOURCETS2', 'TARGETTS1, TARGETTS2,
      SYS_ANY', 'ERRORSCHEMA', 'ERRORNAME')